# Update values in specified columns based on external data table

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I want to update the values in some specified columns of a data table based on external values from another data table.

I know how to do this variable by variable, but I wanted a more efficient solution that I can automate, perhaps using `lapply`

**UPDATE**: My data set (equivalent to `mtcars` in the example below) have other columns which I don't want to update.

## For a reproducible example, run this snippet of code first

```
# Load library
  library(data.table)

# load data
  data(mtcars)

# create another Data Table which we'll use as external reference
# this table shows the number of decimals of those variables we want to modify in mtcars
  var <- c("mpg","disp","hp")
  Decimal <- c(1,3,2)
  DT <- cbind.data.frame(var, Decimal)

# convert into data.table
  setDT(DT)
  setDT(mtcars)
```

## My code, updating column by column

```
mtcars[, mpg  := mpg  / 10 ^ DT[var=="mpg",  Decimal] ]
mtcars[, disp := disp / 10 ^ DT[var=="disp", Decimal] ]
mtcars[, hp   := hp   / 10 ^ DT[var=="hp",   Decimal] ]
```

This code works fine and it gives the desired result.

## Desired Result

The first row of `mtcars` used to look like this:

```
>     mpg disp  hp
> 1: 21.0  160 110
```

and now it looks like this:

```
>     mpg   disp   hp
> 1: 2.10  0.160 1.10
```

Is there a more efficient solution using `function` , `lapply` etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can also use `set` for multiple columns.  It is very efficient as the overhead of `[.data.table` is avoided.  We loop over the column index of 'mtcars', and use `set` to change the columns specified by 'j' with the `value` from the calculation of corresponding 'mtcars' columns with 'DT$Decimal' elements.

```
for(j in seq_along(mtcars)){
  set(mtcars, i=NULL, j=j, value=mtcars[[j]]/10^DT[,Decimal][j])
 }


head(mtcars)
#    mpg  disp   hp
#1: 2.10 0.160 1.10
#2: 2.10 0.160 1.10
#3: 2.28 0.108 0.93
#4: 2.14 0.258 1.10
#5: 1.87 0.360 1.75
#6: 1.81 0.225 1.05
```

EDIT: Based on the OP's comments, suppose if we are not subsetting the dataset and want to keep all the columns, while transforming some columns specified in the 'var', we can loop over the 'var' and use `set` to change the columns specified by the 'var'.  Here, I am using the full `mtcars` dataset after converting to `data.table`.

```
 for(j in seq_along(var)){
  set(mtcars, i=NULL, j=var[j], value=mtcars[[var[j]]]/10^DT[, Decimal][j])
 }

head(mtcars)
#    mpg cyl  disp   hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1: 2.10   6 0.160 1.10 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#2: 2.10   6 0.160 1.10 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#3: 2.28   4 0.108 0.93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#4: 2.14   6 0.258 1.10 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#5: 1.87   8 0.360 1.75 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#6: 1.81   6 0.225 1.05 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: I should have been clearer, @akrun. Now it's working perfectly !

Answer (score 4):

Looks like `Map()` would do it

```
library(data.table)
## match 'DT$var' to the names of 'mtcars'
m <- chmatch(levels(DT$var)[DT$var], names(mtcars))
## update 'mtcars' with the desired operation
mtcars[, names(mtcars) := Map("/", .SD, 10 ^ DT$Decimal[m])]
## result
head(mtcars)
#     mpg  disp   hp
# 1: 2.10 0.160 1.10
# 2: 2.10 0.160 1.10
# 3: 2.28 0.108 0.93
# 4: 2.14 0.258 1.10
# 5: 1.87 0.360 1.75
# 6: 1.81 0.225 1.05
```

Or if you want to go a little faster we can use `.mapply()` in place of `Map()` that call would be

```
.mapply(`/`, list(.SD, 10 ^ DT$Decimal[match(DT$var, names(mtcars))]), NULL)
```

Comment: this would require twice the memory of the object though.

Comment: @Arun - Should it be `mtcars[, names(mtcars) := Map("/", .SD, DT$Decimal)]
` then?

Comment: The problem is that lapply etc and map first has to return the entire list before being assigned. So we can't avoid the memory requirements unless we go for a for loop... 

Comment: But may be we could catch these and oprimise internally. Great point!